# How does Obito have two Sharingans if Madara took one?

Tags: naruto

If Madara took Obito's left eye, how come he has both Sharingans? (Chapter 683, page 15) Did Obito replace the one he lost with Kakashi's Sharingan, like a trade?

Comment: Welcome to Anime and Manga. To my understanding the site you linked to was an illegal manga site. if i am wrong someone can rollback my edit

Answer (score 7):

**TL;DR:**
Because Madara gave him the Sharingan he had taken from Kakashi back when he took the Rinnegan Obito had in his left eye socket.

**Long version:**
In chapter 674, page 14, Madara takes Kakashi's Sharingan eye (Obito's left eye):

[image: Naruto chapter 674 page 14]

In chapter 675, page 10, Madara switches his left eye - currently holding Obito's left eye - for the Rinnegan Obito has in his left eye socket:

[image: Naruto chapter 675 page 10]

In that same chapter, he lets Black Zetsu take control of Obito's left side. In chapter 676, page 2, we see that Obito now has both of his Sharingan, though he is not in control of his body:

[image: Naruto chapter 676 page 2]

In chapter 679, page 6, Black Zetsu leaves Obito's body to join Kaguya:

[image: Naruto chapter 679 page 6]

Leaving him finally in control of both of his Sharingan when Naruto revives him and he regains consciousness in chapter 683, page 6:

[image: Naruto chapter 683 page 6]

Answer (score 4):

> Obito had his Right eye Kamui Sharingan and Madaras Rinnegan in his
>   left socket. Madara snatched Kakashis Kamui Sharingan and used it to
>   enter Kamui Dimension and retrieve his Rinnegan. He was successful and
>   Black Zetsu possessed Obitos right body half, which was eyeless until
>   Madara popped Kakashis Sharingan in. Obito got both his eyes back in
>   that moment, but B Zetsu was using the Obitos right half and used
>   Kakashis eye to get himself and Madara out of the dimension..  It was
>   mentioned, but it was easyly possible to miss.. I thought for quite a
>   while that Obito didn't have both of his eyes until it was cleared up
>   to me, that the Obitos right eye was never touched by madara.. thus
>   giving him both eyes. Why did Madara pop Kakashis Kamui eye back? I
>   don't know... Lets just say for plot, because he could have just
>   crushed it. I'd assume he didn't consider Obito a threat anymore and
>   wanted the MS Sharingan as backup for whatever reason.. It really
>   caused a stir here when those chapters came around
>
> The "unmentioned" situation you're looking for spans from chapter 674
>   to 676.

-KuramaErricson

This is the answer given by that person, you can refer to his post here. http://forums.mangafox.me/threads/511150-How-did-Obito-get-his-left-eye-back

Answer (score 0):

He gave it black zetsu to use madara and himself to get out of the dimension madara basically madara put his rennigan on while he was in the other dimension and only way to get out is with obitos sharingan capish

Comment: Can you provide any sources (such as chapter or episode numbers) for this?